# jquery slider on site

Tags: jquery

I need to set [this](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/magento_39139/) slider on site. I create same html form. Connected scripts:
jquery.min.js
jquery.easing.1.3.js, tms-0.3.js, tms_presets.js

and call code

```
<script>
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        jQuery('.slider')._TMS({
            duration:600,
            easing:'easeOutQuad',
            preset:'simpleFade',
            nextBu:'.slider-next',
            prevBu:'.slider-prev',
            slideshow:9000,
            banners:'fromLeft',
            waitBannerAnimation:false,
            pauseOnHover:true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Pictures move is works, but text not moving. Particularly container with "banner" class.
Tnx advance.

[Link](http://pr2.zoo.dmsh1.kz/index.html) to html page

Comment: You are linking to a far file... Can you describe the problem more precise, or fix the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your HTML

Just comparing your HTML file and the live site

Yours looks like

```
<ul class="items">
<li>
     <img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/magento_39139/skin/frontend/default/theme321/images/media/slider1.png" alt="">
</li>
<li>
    <img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/magento_39139/skin/frontend/default/theme321/images/media/slider2.png" alt="">
</li>
<li>
  <img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/magento_39139/skin/frontend/default/theme321/images/media/slider3.png" alt="">
</li>
```

followed by your divs

```
<div class="banner">
<!--code here -->
</div>
```

This should be

```
     <li><img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/magento_39139/skin/frontend/default/theme321/images/media/slider1.png" alt="">
       <!-- place your banner code within the li tags-->
            <div class="banner">
              <div class="banner-padding">
                <div class="slog-banner">
                   <span class="banner-title">Philips </span>
                   <span class="banner-slog">Medical Equipment (CY-A03)</span>
                   <span class="banner-desc">Ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</span>
                   <a class="banner-button" href="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/magento_39139/diagnostic-supplies/heavy-duty-x-ray-system.html/">Read more</a>
                </div>
           </div>
         </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: No worries - good luck - firebug is a plugin in firefox that should become your best friend